# React-Bootstrap Form.File and bs-custom-file-input. Can't get label to change

Tags: react-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the text box label to change on my File upload.  I'm using React-Bootstraps Form.File component and read that bs-custom-file-input will work.  My general code is as follows

```
import bsCustomFileInput from "bs-custom-file-input"
```

then in my useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {bsCustomFileInput.init()}, [])
```

finally in my form

```
<Form.Group as={Row}>
     <Form.File
          type="file"
           className="custom-file-label"
           id="inputGroupFile01"
           label="Upload Boundary File"
           custom
      />
</Form.Group>
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?  Nothing happens with my File input box after selecting the file.  Or how do i troubleshoot?  I inspected the HTML and the classes and id values look correct.  How can I tell if the bsCustomFileInput.init() loaded or is being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example snippet is working on my end: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-swirles-2cejw?file=/src/index.js. But, it does have a `z-index` issue - you can take a look at styles.css in the sandbox for that.

However, I don't think you need that library for this specific requirement. You can just store the current file name in a state and control the `label` prop of `Form.File`

```
function App() {
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("Upload Boundary File");

  return (
    <>
      <Form.Group as={Row}>
        <Form.File
          type="file"
          className="custom-file-label"
          id="inputGroupFile01"
          label={fileName}
          onChange={(e) => setFileName(e.target.files[0].name)}
          custom
        />
      </Form.Group>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit romantic-allen-2evjy]

Comment: According tot he API docs Form.File doesn't have an onChange event.  When I tried your suggestion and console.log(e.target) all I got was the htrml for Form.File.  I still have no idea how to troubleshoot why bs-custom-file-input isn't working.  I don't get any errors in console

Comment: use `e.target.files[0].name` and you are done. As for `bs-custom-file-input` it works on my sandbox. take a look at the package versions i used -  could be a factor

Comment: thanks.  removed the type="file" and got it working.  Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea shared in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64079775/7048915) from user [95faf8e76605e973](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8680805/95faf8e76605e973), I ended up with the following:

My form component:

```
          <Form key={`upload_${image_type}`}>
            <div key={`${image_type}`} className="mb-3">
              <Form.File
                id={`upload_${image_type}`}
                key={`upload_${image_type}`}
                label={this.state.upload_image[`${image_type}`]["label"]}
                custom
                onChange={this.FileUploadHandler.bind(this, image_type)}
              />
            </div>
          </Form>
```

The fileUploadHandler function invoked on change:

```
  FileUploadHandler = (image_type, e) => {
    if (e.target.files) {
      console.log(e.target.files);
      let file = e.target.files[0];
      if (file) {
        let current_state = this.state.upload_image;
        current_state[image_type]["label"] = file.name;
        current_state[image_type]["file"] = file;
        this.setState({ upload_image: current_state });
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Nope");
    }
  };
```

The state set in my class component's constructor:

```
export class PackageInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      upload_image: {
        Wallpaper: { label: "Upload File...", file: "No file selected" },
        RotationBanner: { label: "Upload File...", file: "No file selected" },
        BootBanner: { label: "Upload File...", file: "No file selected" },
        Installer: { label: "Upload File...", file: "No file selected" },
        AppPage: { label: "Upload File...", file: "No file selected" },
        Featured: { label: "Upload File...", file: "No file selected" },
        RotationBanner: { label: "Upload File...", file: "No file selected" },
        Logo: { label: "Upload File...", file: "No file selected" },
        GameTVBanner: { label: "Upload File...", file: "No file selected" },
        GameTiles: { label: "Upload File...", file: "No file selected" },
      },
    };
  }
```