# How can be customized file input label and placeholder in react-bootstrap?

Tags: file, react-bootstrap, input-field

I try to customize a file input's label and placeholder in react-bootstrap but cannot find a way to do it.

In the react-bootrap docs, there is nothing about customization:
https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/forms/form-control/#file-input

neihter in the bootstrap 5 docs:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#file-input

I also found this: [React-Bootstrap Form.File and bs-custom-file-input. Can't get label to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076013/react-bootstrap-form-file-and-bs-custom-file-input-cant-get-label-to-change)

but I don't want to use another library if it is possible. ( And it is for bootstrap 4.)

This is my code:

```
<Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formFile">
  <Form.Label>Kép</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control ref={fileRef} type="file"/>
</Form.Group>
```

Comment: File input fields don't allow for much customizing, hardly any. If you want anything else than whatever file upload button with different button texts different browsers will show you by default - then you need a solution that _hides_ the native input field. The click on its associated label will still trigger the file selection dialog - but whatever UI you want to _show_ the user the name of the selected file(s), you will need to build yourself using additional JavaScript, starting with reading the list of selected files.